# Why doesn't $x^2+y^2-4xy$ have a local minimum at $(0,0)$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, maxima-minima

Consider $f(x,y)= x^2+y^2-4xy. \nabla f = (2x-4y, 2y-4x),$ which equals $0$ at $(0,0$). $f_{xx}=2,f_{yy} =2,f_{xy}=f_{yx} = -4.$ Since $f_{xx}f_{yy}<(f_{xy})^2 $, $(0,0)$ is only a saddle point. But since $f_x=f_y=0$ and $f_{xx}, f_{yy}>0$, from the point of view of single variable calculus, shouldn't $(0,0)$ be a local minimum? 
I somehow find this aspect of multivariable calculus much less intuitive. I'd be grateful for any help on this.

Comment: What does the function equal along the line $y=x$?

Comment: Because $f(\epsilon, \epsilon)=-2\epsilon^2$.

Comment: I would recommend to find a tool for 3d plotting of functions (free online tools are available). Once you see the plot you will recognize that $(0,0)$ is a saddle but that the restriction of $f$ to either the $x=0$ plane or the $y=0$ plane has a local minimum at $0$.

Comment: To get an understanding of how these properties can be had look at these graphs:
https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=x%5E2+%2B+y%5E2+-+4xy
https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=x%5E2+%2B+y%5E2+-+4xy+%3D+0
And:
https://tinyurl.com/2s4hp5f8 

The "region of negative values" falls in the upper-right and lower-left quadrants, and does not contain the $X$ or $Y$ axis (apart from the $(0,0)$ point). That's how it can be a saddle despite being a minimum when restricted to either axis.